# Нужен совет в организации данных в БД

Tags: база-данных

Требуется организовать информацию о количестве посещений и выполненных действий пользователей.

Мои размышления:

Создать Таблицы:

- Users,
- Действие(id, Название),
- Операции (id, id_Users, id_Действия, Дата, Количество)

Буду смотреть было ли действие сегодня, если нет, то создаю, иначе увеличиваю счетчик "Количество"

Вот задумался стоит ли Выделать Дату в отдельную сущность и тогда в Операции записывать не дату, а id_Даты. Или это уже чересчур?

Comment: Мне кажется перебор. Логичнее будет, наверное, поставить индекс к операциям `IX_id_Действия_Дата`. Плюс не ошибиться с типом хранения и поставить именно `Date`, а не `DateTime`.

Comment: Дата в зависимости от формата это 4-8 байт, вторая таблица это как минимум дата + ссылка размером 4-8 байт, что вы пытаетесь выгадать вынося дату в отдельную таблицу?

Comment: Кстати нереляционные бд лучше подойдут под эту задачу, нежели реляционные.

Comment: @icYFTL, я наверно неудачно назвал таблицу "Действие" - логика ее в том, чтобы заносит возможное событие, а в таблице "Операции" - брать название события из "Действий".

Comment: @АлексейБелкин, это я понял.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, я просто думаю про поиск, когда данных будет очень много, и думаю, что через ссылку будет фильтрация быстрее, чем через сравнение значений

Comment: Через ссылку - это две операции, сравнить дату и пройти по ссылке, а без ссылки - одна операция- сравнить дату.